# Get Facebook Photos without access token

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I am using **facebook php sdk 4.0** and I want to **fetch all user album photos without user access token**. I don't want user to log in to get access token..Is that possible ?

Comment: It looks like you have an answer below that you can accept, Amb. Would click the tick mark left of the answer?

Answer (score 2):

Obviously, that´s not possible. You MUST use a User Token with the `user_photos` permission to get the albums/photos of a User. And you need to go through a [review](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/login) process with that permission before your App goes public.